# Okta Oauth2 implementation on Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, okta

i am new to Okta, i want to implement okta oautu2 on spring mvc application[without using springboot].
on web i found threads which are based on springboot application.

Comment: Are you OK with using Spring Security? If so, they have an OAuth project that doesn’t require Spring Boot. They also have OIDC support in Spring Security 5.

Comment: Hi Matt...i am ok with spring security, could you please provide the project link...so that i can gone through it....

Comment: Here’s some info on Spring Security and its OAuth and OIDC support. https://spring.io/blog/2018/01/30/next-generation-oauth-2-0-support-with-spring-security

Comment: I’ve written some blog posts on how to use both OAuth and OIDC with Spring Security 5, but they all use Spring Boot. I’m guessing there’s a filter you can use for non-Boot apps.

Comment: Thanks for your help... i will try to implement oauth on spring5.

Comment: Hi Matt...just required one more information regarding OAuth/OIDC. I have one Rest API which is consume by third party applications, so is it possible to put Okta on Rest API? [There is no UI, only Rest web Service]

Comment: You could use OAuth 2.0's client credentials if you need to do server-to-server communication. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/04/02/client-creds-with-spring-boot